# What is the $k$-th derivative of $f(t^a)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What is the $k$-th derivative of $f(t^a)$

$$
\frac{d^k}{dt^k} f(t^a) = ???
$$

In particular I am interested when $a=ib$ for some real number b

I have attempted to define this problem recursively. First let $u_{k,c}(t) = D^kf^{(c)}(t^a)$, where $D$ is the derivative operator and $f^{(c)}(t)$ is the $c$th derivative of $f(t)$.

$$
u_{k,c}(t) = D^kf^{(c)}(t^a) = D^{k-1}Df^{(c)}(t^a)
$$
$$
u_{k,c}(t) = D^{k-1} [ f^{(c+1)}(t^a) a t^{a-1}]
$$

Now using the [Product rule for higher derivatives](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Product_rule_for_higher_derivatives) we can write the following.

$$
u_{k,c}(t) = a \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} {k-1 \choose m} [D^{k-m-1} f^{(c+1)}(t^a)] [D^{m}t^{a-1}]
$$

$$
u_{k,c}(t) = a \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} {k-1 \choose m} u_{k-m-1,c+1}(t) \frac{(a-1)!}{(a-m-1)!}t^{a-m-1}
$$

This is as far as I got. The end case for this is $u_{0,c}(t) = f^{(c)}(t^a)$

Comment: what  did you attempt ?

Comment: I recommend to add this to your question.

Comment: Realized my attempt was false

Comment: updated my attempt

Comment: [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)